# How to prevent login prompt in chrome for 401 Unauthorization error for Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular4-httpclient

> The server was responding with 401 error code against an ajax call and
>   that’s why my chrome browser was throwing an ugly login prompt box,
>   before even my client side 401 handlers were called.

Comment: What is the authentication method you use? You should add headers to your request

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, I have tried a lot of fixes but the easiest one is to include "**X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest**" in the request header. It instantly fixed the issue in chrome. In this case no need to change anything from the server side.

```
this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      authorization: "Basic your_credential"
    });
```

note: this I have used in Angular

Comment: where do you put this statement?

Comment: I had attached it with headers during API calls